# How to download the public key of the AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, key, public-key

A co-worker asked me to share with him my PGP public keys to send us encrypted credentials to access the data. But I don't know how to do that.
It was not me who created my key, it was the former colleague who sent me a csv file with my identifiers:

```
User name,Password,Access key ID,Secret access key,Console login link
elmio@email.com,unpassword, ELACCESSKEYID, S3/CR33T//AcCessKeY , https://numeros.signin.aws.amazon.com/console
```

Then I followed the [documentation to download the public key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/download-public-key.html) but there are no keys:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

I am using Windows10

Answer (score 0):

AWS does not use PGP keys.

The credentials you have shown are used to login to the AWS management console. They are unrelated to encrypting emails.

If you want to use PGP for encrypting email contents, you would do this *outside* of AWS.